# Save changes in xlsm Workbook as xlsx without subsequent user confirmation

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a macro (.xlsm).

In the macro, I want to make changes in thisworkbook (where macro is) and save the organized workbook in the same folder of thisworkbook with a different name (and if possible as a .xlsx file, since I do not need the macro in the final file, if not possible as .xlsm).

After running macro, I do not want the user to do anything. Also, I do not want to save any changes in the original (reference) workbook.

I tried the following: (Assume this is in macro's sub)

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Check if final file exists, if so delete '''''
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    wb.SaveCopyAs (wb.path & "\final.xlsm")

    Dim wbf As Workbook
    Set wbf = Workbooks.Add(wb.path & "\final.xlsm")
    wbf.Activate

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Changes to wbf '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    wbf.Save
```

I (as user) get a selection box:

*" The following features cannot be saved in macro free workbooks*

*" VB project*

*" To save a file with these features, click No, and then choose a macro enabled file type in the File Type list.*

*" To continue saving as a macro free workbook, click Yes*

*"Yes", "No", "Help"*

If I click Yes, it mentions that final1.xlsx already exists, and asks whether to overwrite or not. If click overwrite, the mentioned xlsx file open, final xlsm file gets saved at path.

This situation asks the user to click on something and also displays a new Excel file which I hope to avoid.

Comment: [`Workbook_BeforeSave()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave) events may help you, which is associated with the workbook module, not a general or class module.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` prior to the main code, and set it back to `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after.